# Filling out a website form with excel vba

Tags: html, excel, vba

I have a website that I want to read some data off, do a bunch of calcs, then fill out a form and submit it, all using excel vba.

I can read the website well enough, and do the calcs. I can also fill out a few of the inputs.

However, on this final form, my technique no longer works.

On the first few pages, the html has looked like

```
<input name="ProjectFile-BuildingPermitNumber" class="form-control" type="text" maxlength="100" data-bind="textInput: ProjectFile().BuildingPermitNumber">
```

and i I have been using , with elementname being projectfile-buildingpermitnumber

`IEValue = objIE.document.getElementsByName(ElementName)(0).Value`

to obtain the values and

`objHTML.getElementsByName(ElementName)(0).Value = ValueCheck`

to return them

I have also used

```
Set AllLinks = objIE.document.getElementsByTagName("A")
```

and a for loop to find buttons to click on. not the best technique, i probably should use a .click, but it works.

anyway, on this new form, I do not have an id or name to work with.

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-3 control-label">
<span> Structural</span>
</label>
<div class="input col-sm-7">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" data-bind="value: DrawingsDocuments.Structural">
</div>
</div>
```

Anyone got an idea on how I can refer to these types of boxes using excel? Ive tried all the different getelement etc that MS HTML controls give.

Regards
Bryan

Comment: Anyone at all?? Please point me in the right direction...

Comment: Anyone at all?

Can I put a bounty on a solution? will that help?